# проблема при замене элементов в JSON массиве

Tags: php, массивы, json

Три массива в JSON формате: `properties`, `values` и `items`.
В `properties` и `values` массивы в виде [ключ, значение].
В `items` - код товара и массив из ключей свойств (`properties`) и значений (`values`).

```
{"properties":
[[24,"Процессор"],
[42,"Тип оперативной памяти"],
"values":
[4601,"AMD"],
[2654,"DDR3"],
"items":
{"70109":[[24,4601],[42,2654]
}}
```

Обошел массивы `properties` `values`:

```
`foreach($output->properties as $propkey=>$prop){
   $properties[$prop[0]]=$prop[1];

}
foreach($output->values as $val){
    $values[$val[0]] = $val[1];
}
```

И получил вот такие массивы:

```
$properties=array(
[24] => Процессор
[42] => Тип оперативной памяти
)
$values=array(
    [4601] =>  AMD
    [2654] => DDR3
    )
```

Но никак не могу обработать json массив `items` и заменить ключи `properties` and `values` на их  значения в массиве `items`:

```
"items":
{"70109":[[24,4601],[42,2654]
}}
```

Comment: кривой JSON, исправьте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так

```
foreach($output->items as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $v){
        $items[$key][] = [$properties[$v[0]] => $values[$v[1]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: а как можно такой многомерный массив записать в csv файл?

Comment: @МихаилАнискин, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108157/php-array-to-csv